# Use PHP to extract instances of the occurrence of a word in context, and filter results by certain criteria

Tags: php, regex, nlp

I have an array of strings which are essentially English paragraphs.

I’d like to extract all instances of the word `Act` (with the capital letter) in context. In context here means, I’d like to see `some text some text some text Act some text some text some text`.

Maybe about 12-15 words on the left, and 5-8 words on the right. This is very much like a *corpus concordance* for the word `Act`.

However, I’d like to exclude instances of `Act` where:

1. `Act` [0-2 words] `(Cap.` // i.e when `Act` is followed by 0-2 words and then the string `(Cap.`
2. `Act` [0-2 words `(Act`  // i.e when Act is followed by 0-2 words and then the string `(Act`
3. `[Act` // i.e. when Act is preceded by `[`
4. … and other cases like this…

How would you do this with native PHP or a PHP framework that supports NLP? Please show exactly (ie provide code), even if you use an NLP or other framework or library pls show which functions or objects or methods you use.

I can only use PHP, but if you have other languages in mind which can do this better, please provide in comment. Note I need to interface with MySQL to extract the strings into an array first so the language preferably should support MySQL interfacing.

I can do away with dealing with words and deal with characters instead, if it's difficult to do so in PHP (so eg. I can have 40-45 characters on the left and 20-25 characters on the right as context for the word Act). I don't mind using regex as well.

Answer (score 0):

the first regular answers the criteria 12-15 words on the left, and 5-8 words on the right:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){12,15}Act\s(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){5,8}
```

you should use the negative lookahead

```
^((?!Act\s(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){0,2}Cap | (?!Act\s(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){0,2})Act))(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){12,15}Act\s(([a-zA-Z]{1,})\s){5,8}
```